# How to remove specific release name

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I try to delete a specific release name. i tried a lot thing but unfortunately without success.
Do you know or may be an idea how i can remove it ?

```
karaf$/karaf            0.0.124         1.0             Karaf for kubernetes       
karaf/karaf             0.0.176         1.0             Karaf for kubernetes
```

Comment: Have you tried `helm delete <release_name>`?

Comment: Yes, as said above, also you can add `--purge` flag.

Answer (score 0):

i completly forget to say . when i tried with `helm delete` or with the tag `--purge` nothing change

```
helm search karaf
WARNING: Repo "local" is corrupt or missing. Try 'helm repo update'.NAME                        CHART VERSION   APP VERSION     DESCRIPTION                
karaf$/karaf            0.0.124         1.0             Karaf for kubernetes       
karaf/karaf             0.0.177         1.0             Karaf for kubernetes       

# helm delete --purge karaf
Error: release: "karaf" not found
```

For the other chart it works perfectly. I dont have any problem .

Comment: `helm search` operates on charts, not releases. You can view the installed releases by calling `helm list`